# Text search direction in Vim

Tags: vim

After I search for "foo" by doing "?foo", I can search forward by "n" or backward by "N", however sometimes the n/N directions are flipped in the middle of search. If I restart Vim, it's OK again. What key sequence may I have pressed to cause this? How to revert back to normal mode?

I don't recall that I ever ran into this in old Vi.

EDIT: it's not the *Caps Lock* key. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I guess it's not just the wrapping around at the end/beginning of the file? Or maybe you typed * or something that reverses the search? I know I unintentionally do it a lot of time.

Comment: @Dave Vogt, it's not just end/beginning of the file. I just tested "*", you are right, if I press "*" I can change/correct the search direction. If you put in an answer, I will vote it up and accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can happen if you started out searching backwards with `?foobar`, and you pressed `/` in the middle.  Now you're searching *forward*, so `n` and `N` are switched relative to what you used to have. The same thing will happen if you started with `/` and pressed `?` in the middle.

Comment: Sir you are right. I just tested what you said. Could you tell me what role "*" is playing in this midst?

Comment: @grokus: `*` means to search forward for whatever word is under the cursor.

Comment: @Daenyth, thanks. I always thought that I wasn't too bad at Vim. (I could get things done) Today I'm reconsidering my position.

Comment: and to follow up @Daenyth, you can search backward for whatever word is under the cursor using `#`. These will match only on the full word. To search for the word under the cursor, including inside other words, use `g*`

Answer (score 4):

It sounds stupid but did you checked Caps-Lock?

Comment: yes I did. It was on "off" position. I have seen this behavior so many times so I was finally fed up and decided to get to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 3):

Nathan has already answered *why* this happens, but if you use both directions regularly and want `n` to **always** look ahead and `N` to **always** look back, no matter which way you searched, you can put this in your `.vimrc`:

```
nmap n /<CR>
nmap N ?<CR>
```

`/` and `?` without parameters perform the last search, in their respective (absolute) directions.